# C++ : custom vtable implementation does not work

Tags: c++, vtable

I'm trying to implement a custom vtable to better understand a concept of virtual tables and overriding. For this I have the following 'base' class

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

struct vtable;

class IdentityDocument {
public:
    IdentityDocument()
        : vtable_ptr_(&IdentityDocument::VTABLE),
          unique_id_(++unique_id_count_)
    {
        std::cout << "IdentityDocument::Ctor() : "sv << unique_id_ << std::endl;
    }

    ~IdentityDocument() {
        --unique_id_count_;
        std::cout << "IdentityDocument::Dtor() : "sv << unique_id_ << std::endl;
    }

    IdentityDocument(const IdentityDocument& other)
        : vtable_ptr_(other.vtable_ptr_),
          unique_id_(++unique_id_count_)
    {
        std::cout << "IdentityDocument::CCtor() : "sv << unique_id_ << std::endl;
    }

    IdentityDocument& operator=(const IdentityDocument&) = delete;

    void PrintID() const {
        std::cout << "IdentityDocument::PrintID() : "sv << unique_id_ << std::endl;
    }

    static void PrintUniqueIDCount() {
        std::cout << "unique_id_count_ : "sv << unique_id_count_ << std::endl;
    }

    int GetID() const {
        return unique_id_;
    }

private:
    vtable* vtable_ptr_ = nullptr;

    static int unique_id_count_;
    static vtable VTABLE;
    int unique_id_;
};

struct vtable
{
    void (IdentityDocument::* const PrintID)() const;

    vtable (
        void (IdentityDocument::* const PrintID)() const
    ) : PrintID(PrintID) {}
};

int IdentityDocument::unique_id_count_ = 0;
vtable IdentityDocument::VTABLE = {&IdentityDocument::PrintID};
```

And here is another class that must override `PrintId` method

```
#pragma once

#include "identity_document.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

class Passport {
public:
    Passport()
        : expiration_date_(GetExpirationDate())
    {
        IdentityDocument* base_ptr = reinterpret_cast<IdentityDocument*>(this);
        vtable* vtable_ptr = reinterpret_cast<vtable*>(base_ptr);
        vtable_ptr = &Passport::VTABLE;

        std::cout << "Passport::Ctor()"sv << std::endl;
    }

    Passport(const Passport& other)
        : identity_(other.identity_)
        , expiration_date_(other.expiration_date_)
    {
        IdentityDocument* base_ptr = reinterpret_cast<IdentityDocument*>(this);
        vtable* vtable_ptr = reinterpret_cast<vtable*>(base_ptr);
        vtable_ptr = &Passport::VTABLE;

        std::cout << "Passport::CCtor()"sv << std::endl;
    }

    ~Passport() {
        std::cout << "Passport::Dtor()"sv << std::endl;
    }

    void PrintID() const {
        std::cout << "Passport::PrintID() : "sv << identity_.GetID();
        std::cout << " expiration date : "sv << expiration_date_.tm_mday << "/"sv << expiration_date_.tm_mon << "/"sv
                  << expiration_date_.tm_year + 1900 << std::endl;
    }

    void PrintVisa(const std::string& country) const {
        std::cout << "Passport::PrintVisa("sv << country << ") : "sv << identity_.GetID() << std::endl;
    }

private:
    IdentityDocument identity_;
    const struct tm expiration_date_;
    static vtable VTABLE;

    tm GetExpirationDate() {
        time_t t = time(nullptr);
        tm exp_date = *localtime(&t);
        exp_date.tm_year += 10;
        mktime(&exp_date);
        return exp_date;
    }
};

vtable Passport::VTABLE = {reinterpret_cast<void (IdentityDocument::*)() const>(&Passport::PrintID)};
```

And a short demo :

```
int main() {
    array<IdentityDocument*, 1> docs = { (IdentityDocument*)(new Passport()) };
    for (const auto* doc : docs) {
        doc->PrintID();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I see that the 'derived' method was not called. Am I using a wrong approach to implement a vtable concept?

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Where are you expecting the dynamic binding to occur?

Comment: `Passport` does not inherit from `IdentityDocument` so all of your casts are undefined behavior.

Comment: None of these static variables are serving any purpose. Static variables are *always* resolved at compile-time and cannot be used for dynamic dispatch. I recommend that you forego all of the pointer manipulation (half of those `reinterpret_cast`s are probably undefined behavior and implement your vtable as something like `std::vector<std::function<...>>`. It's the exact same idea without all of the dubious pointer arithmetic, and the type system will work for you instead of against you.

Comment: Short answer:   You never actually use the variables that you have called `vtable_ptr_`.  They point to tables, but there is no code that _uses_ what's stored in them.

Comment: @NathanOliver I expect dynamic binding to be done because the first member of Password class is IdentityDocument with vtable set to Passport members. So that could do the trick

Comment: Dynamic binding is *only* done in C++ with the `virtual` keyword. Naming a variable "vtable" does not make C++ magically treat it as a vtable. If you want to simulate virtual dispatch (which is a good intermediate C++ exercise), you have to do it *all* yourself. The compiler isn't going to take you halfway there. None of your classes in the example above have a vtable as far as the C++ compiler is concerned, and the only way to change that would be to declare `virtual` functions/superclasses, at which point you're not writing a custom implementation anymore

Comment: @DrewDormann and why is it not possible to access a vtable for Password using the first member of this class (IdentityDocument) with vtable set to Password member?

Comment: I think I'm starting to guess what you're attempting.  You put a pointer at the beginnin of your class, where your C++ compiler normally puts its vtable pointer.  So you are expecting vtable lookup to happen because the pointer is there.  Yes?

Comment: @Dmitry Honestly, you should be attempting this in the `C` language, where there is absolutely no virtual functions, and you truly have to make an attempt, at the lowest level, to implement a vtable.  Otherwise you are using wheels that are already invented for the C++ language, whether you use those wheels on purpose or not.

Comment: You keep saying "with vtable set to". That's *not a thing*. C++ doesn't let you "set" vtables. Ever. That's not how the language works. If you try to finagle with pointers and "trick" C++ into thinking there's a vtable somewhere it didn't put one, then that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, you got my idea correctly =)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yes, it's not a vtable like we have when using virtual keyword, it's my attempt to simulate this behavior - that's why I call it vtable

Comment: @Dmitry Only if you use `virtual` will you get dynamic binging.  If you want to do this yourself, then what you need to do is basically put in the code that the compiler would do you you.  The base class will have a table of function pointers and the derived classes will populate that table with the correct function pointers.  Then the base class functions just need check that vtable variable.  If the entry is null, then it knows to use the base class function.  If it is not null, then it calls the function pointed to by the vtable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I simplified my solution and got what I wanted :

```
#include <iostream>
class A;
struct VTable
{
    void (*say_hello)(A*);
};
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        vtable.say_hello = A::sayHello;
    }

    void sayHello()
    {
        vtable.say_hello(this);
    }
    static void sayHello(A* a)
    {
        std::cout << "A::sayHello" << std::endl;
    }
    VTable vtable;
};
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        a.vtable.say_hello = B::sayHello;
    }
    void sayHello()
    {
        a.vtable.say_hello((A*)this);
    }
    static void sayHello(A* a)
    {
        std::cout << "B::sayHello\n" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    A* a = (A*)(new B);
    a->sayHello();
    delete a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I using a wrong approach to implement a vtable concept?

Yes.  You have not written any code that reads your vtable, and the C++ compiler will not generate any code to read your vtable either.

When you declare a member function `virtual`, your compiler needs to call that function in a special way.  Any call to that function **should be looked up in a vtable**.

When a member function is **not** `virtual`, your compiler knows that **it doesn't need to** look up the location of the function.  It knows which function to call.  No lookup needed.

In your code, you have created a vtable, but this line, calling a non-virtual function:

```
doc->PrintID();
```

Does not need a vtable, and does not check for one.

`doc` is an `IdentityDocument*`, so `doc->PrintID()` calls `IdentityDocument::PrintID()`.  No lookup required, no lookup happens.

Comment: the compiler does not know about tables but what about pointer arithmetics? The first member of Passport is IdentityDocument, so I can access it via reinterpret_cast, right? So, using this pointer I can access to it's vtable member, which is in turn set in Password ctor. So it must be ok but still does not work...

Comment: @Dmitry when you write `doc->PrintID();`, since `PrintID` isn't marked `virtual`, the call to `PrintID` is dispatched to the _static_ type of `doc` i.e. `IdentityDocument`. Why would the compiler even bother with what the first member of `Passport` is?

Comment: @Zoso because doc is a pointer to Passport, to be precise to it's first member which is IdentityDocument with vtable struct set to Passport::VTABLES. Am I missing smth?

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, you're missing that you wrote `array<IdentityDocument*, 1>`. The type of `doc` is `IdentityDocument*` ***not*** `Passport*`. You explicitly did a _cast_ when you write `(IdentityDocument*)(new Passport())`. No `virtual` keyword, no polymorphic sauce.

Comment: @Dmitry I suspect that you are having trouble figuring out how virtual functions work because you do not currently have a firm understanding of how non-virtual functions work.  Your comments seem to imply that every function call involves looking for a vtable somewhere, which isn't true.

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding - I reworked my solution and got what I wanted !!!